# Can't remove original markers from map when device is mobile

Tags: javascript, css, mapbox

Im working on a project with mapbox and I have my own icons which I want to use instead the original native markers of mapbox. 
After seeing that the "setIcon" function did not remove the original grey markers but only add my icons next to them, I used this css command to remove them:

```
.leaflet-container img.leaflet-marker-          icon[src~="http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/marker/pin-    m+7e7e7e.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF2aWRoYWxmb24iLCJhIjoibzZhZTlJdyJ9.ab2pmxikBxsmsWEvbfYVfw"]{display:none}
```

It works great on the web, but when I open the website on mobile it does not work and again I see both, my icons and the native markers.

This is my code for replacing the icons:

```
locations.eachLayer(function(locale) {
var prop = locale.feature.properties;
locale.setIcon(L.icon({
    iconUrl: './icon.png',  
}));
});
```

And this is my website:
http://www.david-halfon.com/worldRadio/

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source of your page:

```
var map = map1.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson)
locations = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
locations.setGeoJSON(geojson);
```

You're changing the icons on the `locations` layer, but also adding the same data to the `map1.featureLayer`, and that layer has the default icons.

Comment: Ohh you right. Thanks I'll fix it. But why should it works fine on desktop and not on mobile?

Comment: Because your phone has a retina screen, and so the URL to the marker image automatically switches to an @2x double-size image, and is no longer affected by your CSS rule.